# Golang guard (assert) functions naming convention

Tags: go, naming-conventions, assert, naming

I'm wondering if there is a golang naming convention for guard (assert) functions? I've googled a bit but couldn't find anything definitive. I've read in "The Go Programming Language" book that using 'must' prefix is a common practice.

Example of the function I need:

```
package main

func divide(a, b int) int {
    mustNotBeZero(b)
    return a / b
}

func mustNotBeZero(n int) {
    if n == 0 {
        panic("cannot divide by zero")
    }
}

func main() {
    println(divide(5, 0))
}
```

Comment: Well, this example is a bit strange as it does exactly what it would do without the `mustNotBeZero` guard/assertion: panic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't "part" of any convention, but the [standard library](https://golang.org/pkg/) also uses `MustXX()` functions, so it's a good pattern to follow, if you really need this.

Examples:

Exported:

- [`func MustCompile(str string) *Regexp`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile)
- [`func Must(t *Template, err error) *Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Must)
- [`src/syscall/dll_windows.go`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/dll_windows.go): (on Windows)

  - `func MustLoadDLL(name string) *DLL`
  - `func (d *DLL) MustFindProc(name string) *Proc`

Unexported:

- [`src/cmd/go/go_test.go`](https://golang.org/src/cmd/go/go_test.go):

  - `func (tg *testgoData) must(err error)`
  - `func (tg *testgoData) mustExist(path string)`
  - `func (tg *testgoData) mustNotExist(path string)`
- [`src/encoding/xml/xml.go`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/xml/xml.go):

  - `func (d *Decoder) mustgetc() (b byte, ok bool)`
- [`src/fmt/scan.go`](https://golang.org/src/fmt/scan.go):

  - `func (s *ss) mustReadRune() (r rune)`
- [`src/reflect/value.go`](https://golang.org/src/reflect/value.go):

  - `func (f flag) mustBe(expected Kind)`
  - `func (f flag) mustBeExported()`
  - `func (f flag) mustBeAssignable()`
- [`src/syscall/dll_windows.go`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/dll_windows.go):

  - `func (d *LazyDLL) mustLoad()`
  - `func (p *LazyProc) mustFind()`